# Is $\mathbb{Z}_{10}^*$ cyclic or not?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, solution-verification, modular-arithmetic

Clearly, $\mathbb{Z}_{10}^* = \{[1],[2],[3],[4],[5],[6],[7],[8],[9]\}$. We know that $\mathbb{Z}_{10}^*$ is not a group since $[2]*[5] = [0]$ but $[0] \notin \mathbb{Z}$. Anyway,

We can write:

$$\langle [1]\rangle = \{[1]\}$$

$$\langle [2]\rangle = \{[1], [2], [4], [6], [8]\}$$

$$\langle [3]\rangle = \{[1], [3], [9], [7]\}$$

...

I calculated all the elements and in the end I cannot managed to find a generator. And I concluded that $(\mathbb{Z}_{10}^*,*)$ is not cyclic.

Is it true?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: To get a group you need to take the residue classes mod 10 of those integers relatively prime to 10.  This is the same group mentioned in the comment above.  If that's what you mean it is actually a group of 4 elements, and it is cyclic.

Comment: Clearly $\Bbb Z_{10}^*=U(10)=\{1,3,7,9\}$. It has generator $3$, for example. The star denotes the group of *units*, i.e., $x$ such that $xy=1$ for some $y$.

Comment: Where $\{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9\}$ go?

Comment: They are **not** all units. Look up again the definition of $(\Bbb Z/n\Bbb Z)^*$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that

$$\Bbb Z_{10}^*=\{[a]_{10}\in \Bbb Z_{10}\mid \exists [b]_{10}\in\Bbb Z_{10}, [a]_{10}\times_{10}[b]_{10}=[1]_{10}\},$$

where

$$[a]_{10}\times_{10}[b]_{10}=[ab]_{10}.$$

Its order is $\varphi(10)=4$, where $\varphi$ is Euler's totient function. (Why?)

Since

$$\begin{align}
[3]_{10}^2&=[9]_{10}, \\
[3]_{10}^3&=[3]_{10}\times_{10}[9]_{10}= [7]_{10},
\end{align}$$

and $[3]_{10}^4=[3]_{10}\times_{10}[7]_{10}= [1]_{10}$, we must have that $\Bbb Z_{10}^*$ is generated by $[3]_{10}$.

Hence $\Bbb Z_{10}^*$ is cyclic.